# Vector graphics in Export for Video rendering

Tags: graphics, animation, video

I am trying to generate a vector graphics video in *Mathematica*. I stumbled upon SWF format (PNG are raster images which I'm not interested in). SWF format works fine for me but the axes and the numbers are still in raster.

Following is the minimal code in *Mathematica*

```
m = Manipulate[
  Plot3D[Sin[x y + a], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, Mesh -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> "StarryNightColors"], {a, 0, 4}]

Export["C:\\animated curves\\image-.swf", m, 
 "Scalable" -> True, "ControlAppearance" -> None, 
 ImageResolution -> 300]
```

and to view in $\LaTeX$

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
      \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
          \includemedia[activate=onclick, width=0.5\textwidth]
          {\includegraphics{image-1.png}}{image-.swf}  % generate image-1.png too
        \end{center}
      \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

I could see a long list in `$ExportFormats`, which *Mathematica* supports. However, there are not a handful of vector-graphics format for which `"VideoFrames"` works in `Export`. For instance

```
Export["C:\\Users\\Hawk\\Desktop\\animated curves\\image-.svg", m, "VideoFrames"];
```

generates following warning

> Export::imgseqfmt: SVG is not an export format supported by "VideoFrames." >>

Similar warning appear for EPS format. If there might exist a better solution than SWF from the big pool available in `Export`, please let me inform.

Comment: perhaps `Export` individual files and use an extrnal tool to assemble

Comment: http://www.swftools.org

Comment: Having tried it your first `Export` works fine (I used `Table` instead of `Manipulate` ).  Unfortunately the whole thing appears to be rasterized.  You cannot export a single frame as `swf` so strike my earlier comments.

Comment: my next thought is to export each frame as `pdf` and use `swftools` on that (You will I think need yet another tool to assemble the pdf's into a single document.)

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
ManToGif[man_, name_String, step_Integer] :=
 Export[name <> ".gif",
  Import[
    Export[name <> Which[$OperatingSystem == "MacOSX", ".mov", $OperatingSystem == "Windows", ".avi"],
     man],
    "ImageList"][[1 ;; -1 ;; step]]
  ]
```

**Example use:**

```
   man = Manipulate[ContourPlot[
        q1/Norm[{x, y} - p[[1]]] + q2/Norm[{x, y} - p[[2]]], {x, -2,
         2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> 20, PlotRangePadding -> 0,
        Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 40, ImageSize -> 230,
        ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"], {{q1, -1}, -3, 3}, {{q2, 2}, -3,
        3}, {{p, {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Locator},
       Deployed -> True, FrameMargins -> 0];
```

**Result:**

```
ManToGif[man, "charge", 2]
```

[Reference](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994)

Comment: Still a raster format, though (if I understand the OP correctly, a flash-like vector-based animation is desired).